# problems with x64 compiler while trying to install a scilab toolbox

Tags: 64-bit, scilab

I am trying to install the scilab toolbox "Open Pattern Recognition".
I have installed Microsoft visual studio 10.0 and windows SDKs 7 and 7.1 since Microsoft visual studio has by default only 32x compilers and I have a windows 7 Sp1 64 bit system.

When I try to execute the builder file with scilab (vers. 5.5.2, 64bit) in order to run the installation of the toolbox an error appears:

"NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'"

I have already tried to run the varsall.bat file with the amd 64 option to configure the path environmental variables. When I do this I get the error message: 
”The specified configuration type is missing. The tools for the configuration might not be installed”.

Please, can anyone help me ?